# Init application component with config from database

Tags: php, initialization, yii2, swiftmailer

I'm building a Yii2 application that sends email through the [swiftmailer extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer). I store the email settings (smtp, ssl, username, etc..) in a database table, to be able to edit them with an apposite view.
How can I init swiftmailer with config from the db table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can initialize application components using [set()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-di-servicelocator.html#set%28%29-detail) method available through application object `Yii::$app`:

```
use Yii;

...

// Get config from db here

Yii::$app->set('mailer', [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        // Values from db
        'host' => ... 
        'username' => ...
        'password' => ...
        'port' => ...
        'encryption' => ...
    ],
]);
```

Then use it as usual:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->mailer->...
```

If you want to use the same configuration from database for the whole application, you can get and apply this config during application bootstrap.

Create custom class and place it for example in `app/components`;

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;

class Bootstrap implements BootstrapInterface
{
    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        // Put the code above here but replace Yii::$app with $app
    }
}
```

Then add this in config:

```
return [
    [
        'app\components\Bootstrap',
    ],
];
```

Note that:

> If a component definition with the same ID already exists, it will be
>   overwritten.

Official documentation:

- [BootstrapInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-bootstrapinterface.html)
- [Mailer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to and @arogachev for his answer.that gave me an idea and i solve the problem. i Post this for help anyone

i solve the problem modyfing swiftmailer component, in *Mailer.php* added this:

```
use app\models\Administracion; //The model i needed for access bd
 class Mailer extends BaseMailer
{
...
...
//this parameter is for the config (web.php)
public $CustomMailerConfig = false;
...
...
...
/**
     * Creates Swift mailer instance.
     * @return \Swift_Mailer mailer instance.
     */
    protected function createSwiftMailer()
    {
        if ($this->CustomMailerConfig) {
            $model = new Administracion();

            $this->setTransport([
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => $model->getSmtpHost(),
                'username' => $model->getSmtpUser(),
                'password' => $model->getSmtpPass(),
                'port' => $model->getSmtpPort(),
                'encryption' => $model->getSmtpEncryption(),
            ]);
        }

        return \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($this->getTransport());
    }
```

And in *Web.php* added this:

```
'mailer' => [ 
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'enableSwiftMailerLogging' =>true,
            'CustomMailerConfig' => true, //if its true use the bd config else set the transport here
            'useFileTransport' => false,
],
```