# Config mailer parameters from model - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, mailer

im using Yii2 and i want to config mailer parameters geting the data from db.

Example:

```
'mailer' => [ 
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'enableSwiftMailerLogging' =>true,
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => $model->getSmtpHost(),
                'username' => $model->getSmtpUser(),
                'password' => $model->getSmtpPass(),
                'port' => $model->getSmtpPort(),
                'encryption' => $model->getSmtpEncryption(),
            ],
        ]
```

but from web.php can't call methods from models, i tried but throws a error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Init application component with config from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219440/init-application-component-with-config-from-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Onedev.Link and @arogachev for his answer.that gave me an idea and i solve the problem.

i solve the problem modyfing swiftmailer component, in *Mailer.php* added this:

```
use app\models\Administracion; //The model i needed for access bd
 class Mailer extends BaseMailer
{
...
...
//this parameter is for the config (web.php)
public $CustomMailerConfig = false;
...
...
...
/**
     * Creates Swift mailer instance.
     * @return \Swift_Mailer mailer instance.
     */
    protected function createSwiftMailer()
    {
        if ($this->CustomMailerConfig) {
            $model = new Administracion();

            $this->setTransport([
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => $model->getSmtpHost(),
                'username' => $model->getSmtpUser(),
                'password' => $model->getSmtpPass(),
                'port' => $model->getSmtpPort(),
                'encryption' => $model->getSmtpEncryption(),
            ]);
        }

        return \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($this->getTransport());
    }
```

And in *Web.php* added this:

```
'mailer' => [ 
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'enableSwiftMailerLogging' =>true,
            'CustomMailerConfig' => true, //if its true use the bd config else set the transport here
            'useFileTransport' => false,
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Yii initialized application from this config. You can't use yii2 before yii2 is runned.

```
$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
```

As alternative you can configure mailer after create application in bootstrap.php file like this: `Yii::$app->set('mailer', (new MailerConfigurator())->getConfig());`

Comment: i tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219440/init-application-component-with-config-from-database in a controller, but where call the function i created to set with start the application??

Comment: That is correct answer. `Yii::$app->set()` is not started new application, just change component of [ServiceLocator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-service-locator.html).

Comment: thanks for you answer, gave me an idea, see below @Onedev.Link